# How to save firefox session online?

Tags: windows-xp, firefox, backup

I use this plug-in it is very good but is there a way to save session online ?

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2324

Answer (score 1):

I think [Weave](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/10868) may be what you are looking for.

> The Weave Sync add-on lets you
>   securely take your Firefox experience
>   with you to all your Firefox browsers.
>   You can now surf the Web on your PC,
>   get up and go, and have everything
>   waiting for you on your phone: your
>   history, open tabs, bookmarks, the
>   Awesome Bar – just as you had left it.
>
> Weave Sync currently supports
>   continuous synchronization of your
>   bookmarks, browsing history, saved
>   passwords and tabs.
>
> - Get the same results on the Smart Location Bar on each of your Firefox
>     browsers, so you can get to your
>     favorite sites with just a few
>     keystrokes
> - Continue what you were doing: have the ability to open any tab you have
>     open on any of your Firefox browsers
> - Keep the same list of bookmarks on all of your Firefox browsers
> - Easily sign in to all your favorite sites using your saved passwords (this
>     is especially handy on mobile phones,
>     where it’s hard to type in complex
>     passwords)
> - Do it all securely: Weave Sync encrypts user data before uploading it
>     to Mozilla’s servers, so that only you
>     can access your data

[image]

*Get Up and Go! - With Weave Sync, open web sites on your desktop are instantly available on your mobile device.*

Comment: i don't want to synchronize everything i want to synchronize only saved session

Comment: You can probably turn off what you don't want

Comment: it's overkill for my need I'm already using Diigo toolbar for bookmark synchronization for bookmark and "Session Manager" to save session

Comment: Weave syncs A LOT off things.  But Session Saver's saved sessions isn't one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Agglomerator firefox-extension, You got to get an agglom account, then log in, and you could save the actual firefox tabs session in a set or group of links. But you could syncronize in other firefox installation.

Although this extension is out to date, you could manually install, download the xpi file from agglom webpage, rename the xpi extension to zip file, then extracting and editing the install.rdf file in the line 3.5. *changing to 3.6.* then save and update the compress xpi file, rename the extension to xpi again and manually install in firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Xmarks](http://www.xmarks.com/).  That's what I use now for bookmark sync, and it recently added open-tab syncing.